# Why Facebook messenger keep showing 1 day ago all the time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I have a problem with my Facebook messenger. If I turned on the chat and it showed correctly as Active now with green button. But if I turned off the chat and my last login time will change automatically to 1 day ago even I was still using Facebook application. I reported several times about this problem and no reply yet. Please let me know how to fix it as I don't want my friends assume that I intentionally hide my active status.

Comment: Can you check if the date and time of your device are correct? Or the person you're checking your status on have correct date and time on their device?

Comment: You are facing this issue in mobile or Facebook web application?